# Is there a good way to hash abstract binding trees?

Tags: hash, variable-binding, syntax-trees

The hash function should be invariant under alpha-renaming. Using de Bruijn notation seems to be possible, but it requires alpha-converting the whole tree when a binding is created, and has the unhappy consequence that a substructure of an abt is not a well-formed abs (since the de Bruijn indices are broken). So, is there a good (neat, elegant and/or efficient) way to construct such a function? By the way, is there any study on this matter? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just use de Bruijn indices and live with the overhead. It's smaller than anything else I know of. Regarding subexpressions being broken: no they're not broken, you just need to redefine your notion of "subexpression" because it is not "subtree" anymore (because some nodes in your trees are binders).

Answer (score 0):

I found a paper published two years later. [Hashing modulo alpha-equivalence](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3453483.3454088). This provides an asymptotically faster way to achieve the goal, improving from $O(n^2)$ to $O(n \log^2 n)$.